# Prevent 301 redirect from acting recursively on addon domains (subdirectories)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I want to redirect /index.html to /index.php

```
Redirect 301 /index.html https://www.mymaindomain.co.uk/index.php
```

That works fine but the problem is that it effects all of the addon domains that are on the same server - they all get redirected too (it is cPanel and all addon domains are in subdirectories).

So how can I prevent this redirect acting recursively?

Apologies if this is a duplicate question. I expect that this has been answered before but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [L] flag.

```
RewriteRule ^bla http://www.myurl.com/bla.html [L]
```

When ^bla is the request, and bla.html is the dest.
[Read more](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)